# TLFTextField not found in Flex sdk 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I am trying to use TLFTextField is an AS3 project and I am having some issues compiling some code.I am using FLex SDK 4.6 downloaded from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html.  At the beginning of my class, I use

```
import fl.text.TLFTextField;
public class Homepage{

    private var $:Global = Global.getInstance();
    //Constructor of the background
    public function Homepage(){
    var myTLFTextField:TLFTextField = new TLFTextField();
    myTLFTextField.x = 10;
    myTLFTextField.y = 10;
    myTLFTextField.width = 200
    myTLFTextField.height = 100;
    myTLFTextField.text = "This is my text";
}
```

but I get the error:

```
Error: Definition fl.text:TLFTextField could not be found.
```

So I copied the file tlfRuntime.swc from the flash CS5 application  to the same folder as other libs and the code compiles but nothing gets displayed. 
On the adobe website, it says that the TLFTextField is supported in Flex SDK 4.6 ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/text/TLFTextField.html )

Has anybody got the same issue and managed to get it working ? 
Thanks, 
Cyril

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your answers, it helped me find a solution.

I managed to make the TLFTextField available in the flex SDK  by downloading the latest version of the Flex SDK from the flex.apache.org website (it doesn't seem to work with older versions ) and copy the file (in MAC OS):

```
/Applications/Adobe Flash CS6/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/libs/tlfRuntime.swc
```

to the folder

```
/flex/frameworks/libs/
```

To use it, just use:

```
import fl.text.TLFTextField;
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember LTF always was a separate library (it was just bundled with Flex). You should google for it and download latest version.

Also, it's definitely better to download latest version of Flex as well (in case you are not restricted to previous version). You can do it [here](http://flex.apache.org/). The installer there will also suggest you to download all 3rd parties libs, like TLF.

Comment: It's a Flash CS component, not related to Flex.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to  addChild(myTLFTextField)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the language reference, the fl.* packages are bundled with the Flash Authoring environment. It uses the TLF (Text Layout Framework), but it is not available in Flex or separately bundled.

You can check the availability of classes in [language reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/text/TLFTextField.html), when you filter for products.